# Blender object show blank screen (Min3d)

Tags: android, blender, min3d

I have a blender object and trying to show on the screen on my android phone via min3d,but so far I am getting black blank screen.My object is a simple cube without images.
here is the my code

Main Activity

```
 this.startActivity( new Intent(this,Obj3DView.class));
```

Obj3DView

```
public class Obj3DView extends RendererActivity { 

    private Object3dContainer faceObject3D; /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override public void initScene() 
    {  

    IParser myParser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ, getResources(), "com.example.opengldenemebir:raw/untitled_obj",true); 
    myParser.parse(); 
    faceObject3D = myParser.getParsedObject(); 
    faceObject3D.position().x =1;
            faceObject3D.position().y =1;
            faceObject3D.position().z = 0; 
    faceObject3D.scale().x = faceObject3D.scale().y = faceObject3D.scale().z = 1.009f;
}
```

**log cat shows no error

here is the log cat.
[image]

Comment: I do not know much about min3D. But if it is not working in min3D, you can use [rajawali 3D library](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali). It uses opengl Es 2.0 and has pretty good object parsing APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding light to the scene

```
Light light = new Light();
scene.lights().add(light);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little bit late but it can help someone else. I have been working with min3d and I had the same problem, then I found out why I had the black screen :

1) Check the size and position of your object.

2) Check your mtl file
Try to use these values :

`Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2`

3) Otherwise check youf file names and links : When you export your objects from *Blender*, your original file names are for example `my_model.obj` and `my_model.mtl`. Loading them on android imposes you have different names (without the extension), try calling them : `my_model_obj` and `my_model_mtl`.

The problem with you is maybe because you did not rename the `.mtl` file inside the `.obj` file.

Just check the `.obj` file line
`mtllib my_model.mtl`
and replace it by
`mtllib my_model_mtl`

Works fine for me